# Editing database with dropdown list in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net-2010

I am using asp.net with vb.net code behind.  I have a database that contains a list of names.  I use an asp:dropdownlist databound with SqlDataSourceID and it works fine to get the list from the database to the dropdownlist and display it.

However, I want to use the dropdownlist to also allow the user to add unique values to the dropdownlist and therefore edit the database.

How do I do this? I cannot enter unique values in the dropdownlist now.  Below is the asp snippet.

Thanks for the help.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="OEMDropDownLst" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"  
                CssClass="NwDrpDwnFmt" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataValueField="CustomerName" 
                AppendDataBoundItems="True">  
</aso:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want users to type directly into your dropdownlist? As far as I know that can't be done.  If you want users to add new options to that dropdownlist then you have to create the fields needed and have an update button so then you rebind the dropdownlist after changes have been saved.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>`</aso:DropDownList>`</strike>`</asp:DropDownList>` Spelling mistake brother.